# SOAP action error from AXIS

Tags: c#, java, .net, soap, soap-client

I'm consuming a Java based Web Service with C# .NET app.

I'm sending a SOAP message in XML format.

But I'm receiving this error message:

> ns1:Client.NoSOAPAction no SOAPAction header

Comment: It kind of sounds like you're building the request manually.  Since it's a SOAP service, you should be able to generate a proxy either in VS (add service reference) or with wsdl.exe.  That proxy should generate the correct request xml and headers, including SOAPAction.

If you're doing this and it's still not working, as James Anderson said, you might want to check the WSDL being returned by the java service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the WSDL for your service.

The SOAPAction is effectivly the URL you are sending the soap envelope to, so whatever software you are using should set this up in the http headers.